# Problem with workspace switching

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu 13.04, to move an application from one workspace to other, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ the side of switching used to work. Now, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd> work, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> don't work. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> , <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, all arrow buttons work individually.

Any possible cause of this malfunction?

EDIT1: I indeed have 4 work spaces, although I cannot shift programs to them, I can use them normally.

OS:Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Are you sure you have 4 workspaces? If yes then go through the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Install `CompizConfig Settings Manager` (via the software center)

open CompizConfig and click on `desktop wall`[image]

now go to the Bindings tab and click 'Move with window within wall'[image].

Here you should be able to change the key bindings of moving up and down with window.

Comment: I once screwed my Ubuntu mishandling `ccsm`. Isn't there any other way of solving this by editing some file or something?

Comment: If you only change these settings you should be fine, but probably there is a way to do it in a other way, but I don't know how...